# NG04005: Invalid number of '../'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

When I have the below route

```
 <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['../../mfe-h/admin/dashboard']"><span>Home</span></a>
```

**Exception**

```
Error: NG04005: Invalid number of '../'
    at createPositionApplyingDoubleDots (router.mjs:1082:19)
    at findStartingPosition (router.mjs:1072:12)
    at createTreeUsingPathIndex (router.mjs:907:34)
    at createUrlTree (router.mjs:917:20)
    at Router.createUrlTree (router.mjs:5245:16)
    at get urlTree [as urlTree] (router.mjs:5829:28)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.updateTargetUrlAndHref (router.mjs:5821:26)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.ngOnChanges (router.mjs:5797:14)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1523:14)
```

**Routes**

```
const adminRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'mfe-h',
    component: AdminToolbarComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: AdminDashboardComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any answer for that?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an official documentation for this, but after debugging it turns out that the cause of this error is the additional `/..` you've added to a `routerLink` or to your `navigate` function.
Consider the following app-routing structure:

```
[
    {
        path: 'app'
        children:[{path: 'child'}]
    }
]
```

Now, when you're on `app/child`, you can navigate up to path `app` by just passing `./..` to your `ruoterLink/navigate`.

But, if you'll pass too many `/..`, something like `./../../..`, you are actually trying to navigate higher than the routing tree enables. In this case, Angular will ignore the additional `/..`, but will throw the `NG04005` Error in order to indicate that something is wrong with the given path.

Answer (score 0):

Many a times these errors appears because in .html file something similar to this **[routerLink]="'../../../job-notification'"** must be present use something alternate to this to navigate to the desired route. For eg. router.navigate(['/job-notification']) in .ts file.

I was having similar issue I have solved by removing the routerLink line from my html.